# Calculating two different SUM based on a value of 3rd column

Tags: sql-server

Lets say that we have a "**sales**" table as you can see below. 
Table contains **Qty**, **Price** and if it is taxable or not taxable. I would like to calculate the taxable totals and non-taxable totals.

```
ID  Qty Price Taxable
--  --- ----- -------       
 1    1   5.0       1
 2    2  10.0       1 
 3    2  10.0       1 
 4    4   5.0       1 
 5    5  15.0       1 
 6    5   5.0       1 
 7    4  20.0       0 
 8    3  10.0       0 
 9    3  10.0       0
```

what is the easiest and the fastest way to generate totals of (Qty * Price)  in **two different columns** based on the Taxable column's value is 1 or 0

```
TotalNoTax TotalTax
---------- -------- 
    140.00    165.0
```

Comment: Be great to see what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Try below to get the desired result -***

**Sample Table with Data**

```
Declare @data table 
(ID int, Qty int, Price decimal(5,2), Taxable int)

insert into @data
(id, qty, price, taxable)
values
( 1,    1 ,  5.0  ,     1),
( 2,    2 , 10.0  ,     1), 
( 3,    2 , 10.0  ,     1), 
( 4,    4 ,  5.0  ,     1), 
( 5,    5 , 15.0  ,     1), 
( 6,    5 ,  5.0  ,     1), 
( 7,    4 , 20.0  ,     0), 
( 8,    3 , 10.0  ,     0), 
( 9,    3 , 10.0  ,     0)
```

**Query**

```
Select 
    Sum(Case Taxable when 0  then (Qty * Price) else 0  end ) TotalNoTax, 
    Sum(Case Taxable when 1  then (Qty * Price) else 0  end ) TotalTax 
From @data
```